# Visual Studio crashes because of UserControl automation

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, ui-automation

I need my UserControl to push through a value (using `IValueProvider`) for UI testing and it seems to work except when I try to add or edit the properties of a userControl using the designer of the form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Automation.Provider;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, IValueProvider, IRawElementProviderSimple
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case NativeUIA.WM_GETOBJECT:
                    {
                        // If the window is being asked for a UIA provider, return ourselves.
                        if (m.LParam == NativeUIA.UiaRootObjectId)
                        {
                            m.Result = NativeUIA.UiaReturnRawElementProvider(this.Handle, m.WParam, m.LParam, this);
                            return;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        public string label
        {
            get { return label1.Text; }
            set { label1.Text = value; }
        }

        public bool required
        {
            get { return required; }
            set { label1.Text = label + "*"; }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool IsReadOnly { get => true; }

        public void SetValue(string value)
        {
            // Any attempt to set teh value has no effect.
        }

        public object GetPatternProvider(int patternId)
        {
            if ((patternId == ValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern.Id))
            {
                return this;
            }

            if (patternId == ValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern.Id)
            {
                return this;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public object GetPropertyValue(int propertyId)
        {
            if (propertyId == AutomationElementIdentifiers.NameProperty.Id)
            {
                return this.Name;
            }
            else if (propertyId == AutomationElementIdentifiers.LocalizedControlTypeProperty.Id)
            {
                return "boo";
            }

            return null;
        }

        public IRawElementProviderSimple HostRawElementProvider
        {
            get
            {
                return AutomationInteropProvider.HostProviderFromHandle(this.Handle);
            }
        }

        public ProviderOptions ProviderOptions
        {
            get
            {
                return ProviderOptions.ServerSideProvider | ProviderOptions.UseComThreading;
            }
        }
    }

    public class NativeUIA
    {
        [DllImport("UIAutomationCore.dll", EntryPoint = "UiaReturnRawElementProvider", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr UiaReturnRawElementProvider(
            IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, IRawElementProviderSimple el);

        [DllImport("UIAutomationCore.dll", EntryPoint = "UiaHostProviderFromHwnd", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int UiaHostProviderFromHwnd(
            IntPtr hwnd,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IRawElementProviderSimple provider);

        public const int WM_GETOBJECT = 0x003D;
        public static IntPtr UiaRootObjectId = (IntPtr)(-25);
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be caused by the `UIAutomationCore.dll`.

I am using the .NET 4.8 Framework.

I tried using `interop.UIAutomationCore` nuget package, but that didn't seem to work so I reverted the code to before i used it where it was at least semi functional.

Comment: Try use [DesignMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.designmode?view=netframework-4.8.1) to avoid running problematic code in the designer.

Comment: I tried adding this and used it as a check before the code that crashes my VS(atleast i think) happens and it did nto seem to help

Comment: Have you tried to mark those properties with [BrosableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?view=net-8.0) set to false?